# Why this code takes very long time to run?

Tags: python, list

I have a list
`[4,73,67,38,33]`

and I want to round up this list by using function called gradingStudents. The code is like this

```
def gradingStudents(grades):
    for grade in grades:
        if grade < 38:
            grades.append(grade)
        else:
            roundgrade = round(grade/5)*5
            if roundgrade - grade < 3:
                grades.append(roundgrade)
            else:
                grades.append(grade)
    return grades

grades = []
gradingStudents([4,73,67,38,33])
print(grades)
```

The expected output is like this
`[4,75,67,40,33]`

The problem is the code really takes long time to run. What mistake just I did? Can you figure out?

Comment: Looks like you are looping through a list that keeps growing because you are appending to it.

Comment: `grades` in the function is not the same `grades` in `grades = []`

Answer (score 1):

I made a mistake in my function.
The code should be like this

```
def gradingStudents(grades):
    result = []
    for grade in grades:
        if grade < 38:
            result.append(grade)
        else:
            roundgrade = round(grade/5)*5
            if roundgrade - grade < 3:
                result.append(roundgrade)
            else:
                result.append(grade)
    return result
```

```
print(gradingStudents([4,73,67,38,33]))
```

It will work as I expected

Comment: Be careful: your question sais "I want to round up this list", which means that your solution needs to modify the existing list (hence the proposal in my answer). What you are doing, is making a new list. This might be ok for your current situation, but in some cases that won't be what was requested.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this:

```
for each grade in grades:
  grades.append(...)
```

This goes through your list and keeps on appending and making it longer (which is not what you want: you start with a list of five and want to finish with a list of five).

So you should be doing this: (pseudo-code)

```
for (int i = 0 to grades.length() - 1):
  if grades[i] == ...
  then grades[i] = ...
```

In this way you will replace the items in your list instead of appending.

Answer (score 0):

Make your life easier, and seprate the list creation/modification part and the recalculation part.

Create a function for your intended recalculation:

```
def round_grade(grade):
    if grade >= 38:
        rounded = round(grade / 5) * 5
        if rounded - grade < 3:
            return rounded
    return grade
```

Then just map it to all elements of your list:

```
grades = [4, 73, 67, 38, 33]
new_grades = list(map(round_grade, grades)) # [4, 75, 65, 40, 33]
```